# OrmLite/MySql/SqlExpressionVisitor - need "like" clause

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to LINQ and OrmLite/MySql.  I have a service request argument that needs to result in a where clause:

```sql
`Name` LIKE '%something%' OR `Name` LIKE '%something%else%'
```

I know I can create an `IN()` or an `=` clause, via:

```cs
ev.Where(rn => Sql.In(rn.Name, request.Name));  // Assuming an array here
ev.Where(rn => rn.Name== request.Name));
```

But I can't seem to find a construct that lets me build up a `LIKE`. Also, `Name` is actually an alias so I am trying to avoid constructing the where clause manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build that particular example using `Contains`, i.e:

```
ev.Where(rn => rn.Contains(rn.Name, "something") 
    || rn.Contains(rn.Name, "something%else"));
```

`StartsWith` and `EndsWith` are generally used in LINQ to generate `LIKE` clauses with a wildcard at only one end (but it does appear the MySql dialect defines `StartsWith` somewhat [differently](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql/MySqlExpressionVisitor.cs), likely for efficiency.)

You can check the default dialect [source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/SqlExpressionVisitor.cs) to confirm what gets generated for `EndsWith` and `Contains`.